# Error al llamar a la url desde el templateReverse

Tags: django

Cuando trato de llamar la url desde el template da el siguiente error:

> Reverse for 'todo-add_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments
>   '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

les dejo mis url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from todo import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.list_lists, name="todo-lists"),
url(r'^mine/$', views.view_list, {'list_slug': 'mine'}, name="todo-mine"),
url(r'^(?P<list_id>\d{1,4})/(?P<list_slug>[\w-]+)/delete$', views.del_list, name="todo-del_list"),
url(r'^task/(?P<task_id>\d{1,6})$', views.view_task, name='todo-task_detail'),
url(r'^(?P<list_id>\d{1,4})/(?P<list_slug>[\w-]+)$', views.view_list, name='todo-incomplete_tasks'),
url(r'^(?P<list_id>\d{1,4})/(?P<list_slug>[\w-]+)/completed$', views.view_list, {'view_completed': True},
    name='todo-completed_tasks'),
url(r'^add_list/$', 'todo.views.add_list', name="todo-add_list"),

url(r'^search-post/$', views.search_post, name="todo-search-post"),
url(r'^search/$', views.search, name="todo-search"),

# View reorder_tasks is only called by JQuery for drag/drop task ordering
url(r'^reorder_tasks/$', views.reorder_tasks, name="todo-reorder_tasks"),

url(r'^ticket/add/$', views.external_add, name="todo-external-add"),
url(r'^recent/added/$', views.view_list, {'list_slug': 'recent-add'}, name="todo-recently_added"),
url(r'^recent/completed/$', views.view_list, {'list_slug': 'recent-complete'},
    name="todo-recently_completed"),
```

y esta es la seccion donde llamo la ulr

```
 <p><a href="{% url 'todo-add_list' %}">Create new todo list</a></p>
```

Comment: Ese fichero urls es el del proyecto o el de una aplicación? Está la aplicación en el settings INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: es de el proyecto